# Why Includes are ignored in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have 2 entities.

First entity:

```
 public WorkItem()
        {
            this.Usage = new Collection<ItemUsage>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ItemUsage> Usage { get; set; }
```

and second entity:

```
  public class ItemUsage
    {
        public ItemUsage()
        {
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int WorkItemId { get; set; }

        public string UsedFor { get; set; }

        public virtual WorkItem WorkItem { get; set; }
    }
```

But when I try to get all the work Items the list of Usage is empty. Even if I add include.

```
 var all = EntitySet.Include(i => i.Usage).ToList();
```

Lazy loading is disabled. Do you have any idea of what is wrong?

If I check the query in dbset, there is no Join with the second table.

```
{SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description]
    FROM [dbo].[WorkItem] AS [Extent1]
}
```

EDIT:
Configurations:

```
    entity.HasKey(f => f.Id);
    entity.Property(f => f.UsedFor).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(1000);

    entity.HasRequired(f => f.WorkItem).WithMany(s => s.Usage).HasForeignKey(s => s.WorkItemId).WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

and

```
    entity.HasKey(f => f.Id);
    entity.Property(f => f.Id).HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    entity.Property(f => f.Description).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(1000);

    entity.HasMany(s => s.Usage).WithRequired(s => s.WorkItem).HasForeignKey(s => s.WorkItemId).WillCascadeOnDelete();
```

Comment: Are all the foreign keys created?

Comment: How is lazy loading disabled? What happen when you access the Usage property?

Comment: There is only one foreign key (WorkItemId ) and yes it is created. Usage property is empty list (even if there is data in db). I disabled lazy loading with next code line : Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;, but even if is set to true it is all same.

Comment: @Raskolnikov stupid question: are there ItemUsage data in the DB? Because everything looks correct ;)

Comment: :) Yes there are ItemUsage I DB. I will include configurations in my question. Maybe is something wrong there.

Comment: maybe try generate model with reverse engineering code first

Comment: what is `EnitySet`? Is it just normal `DbSet<WorkItem>` from your context?

Comment: @astef Yes, Just normal DbSet<WorkItem>

Comment: What do you mean by "check the query in dbset"? Are you using `Database.Log` delegate? I have one version which describes everything except your sql log

Comment: If I remove Include(just return EntitySet), and if set LazyLoadingEnabled = true than it is working ! So problem must be with include.

Comment: @sdsf I check query in DbSet while I debugging. I dont have data base log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You're not checking the query by pointing to a `DbSet` while debugging. To check which query is actually sent to a database you must use `Database.Log` property - [Context Log property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx#Log)

I'm pretty sure your query is OK and has a join with second table.

2. You're deleting your results in the constructor with this line:

   ```
       this.Usage = new Collection<ItemUsage>();
   ```

   EF generates a proxy which inherits from your entity, overrides navigation property and sets own collection to it. Your constructor is called after proxie's since your entity class is the base class for a proxy. Just delete your constructor and it will work.

I prefer this style of navigation properties initialization in my entities:

```
class WorkItem
{
    private ICollection<ItemUsage> _usage;

    public virtual ICollection<ItemUsage> Usage
    {
        get { return _usage ?? (_usage = new Collection<ItemUsage>()); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. If I just remove constructor than Usage is null. An query from my log file is without join. Query is : SELECT 
    [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id], 
    [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description]
    FROM [dbo].[WorkItem] AS [Extent1]

Comment: Then you need to isolate the problem by creating minimal example which reproduce it, and show here the code. And again, be sure that sql you're posting here is from log, and not from DbSet's ToString representation